# How to select multiple files of same format except a specific name in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have multiple .txt files to include in gitignore. Also, I need a few of the .txt files to be commited.

Presently, I'm doing:
1) *.txt in .gitignore
2) Followed by git add -f fill_2_add.txt

Is there a way to avoid forcefully including the required .txt files?
I tried using '!fill_2_add!.txt' as given in documentation but to no avail

Comment: 1. It depends on the order in which the patterns are given in `.gitignore`. 2. When you specify an exclamation mark *in* the file name that is actually not there, the file name cannot match.

Answer (score 2):

The rules in `.gitignore` are applied in order and can be negated by starting the line with `!`. For your use-case this means you have to first ignore all *.txt files and then list all individual *.txt files you want to include, i.e. with this .gitignore:

```
*.txt
!fill_2_add.txt
```

Comment: I was thrown off from the example in their documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore where they listed "\!important!.txt" as an example. Inserting '!' only at the start solved this issue.